# Why does my battlelog show two different kill totals for the same Vehicle?

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

[Shown here:](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/soldier/Zerostack/vehicles/342748581/1/#vehicle-air-helicopter-scout)

[image]

What is the difference between the Z-11W and the.... Z-11W ?

Is this a glitch in the battlelog?

Comment: Haven't played BF4 in a while, maybe it's separating kills made by passenger/driver? FWIW, those kills don't add up to the total anyway - I've always found BF's kill tracking to be a little…off.

Comment: @Gauzy Actually, the kills do add up to the total. It probably really depends on the different sides you play on and they just didn't add "Russian" and "Chinese" in the stats.

Comment: @DominicDeCoco Not sure what math I was using, oops!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is a glitch.

Normally, there are three different vehicles (one for each country) of the same vehicle category (MBT, IFV, AA, etc.) but for some vehicle categories (e.g. Scout Heli, Fast Attack Craft) there are only two. The reason you see two Z-11W-s is because both Russians and Chinese use the same chopper Z-11W whereas USA uses the Little Bird. Please note that in real world, Russia and China are political (and therefore military) allies.

The same can be said about Fast Attack Craft DV-15. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this is the reason. Super annoying IMO

Comment: Technically the Russian and Chinese leadership had a well publicized split decades ago, though they still both use weapons descendent from Soviets.